# MySQL Regexp to match image links

Tags: mysql, regex

I tried this expression

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE COL REGEXP "^([%\w-]+\.(?:jpe?g¦JPE?G¦gif¦GIF¦png¦PNG))$"
```

Please help me

Comment: how are these `image links` stored in the table

Comment: image links is http://(.*?)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|bmp)

Answer (score 3):

@Thoman I assume that the column stores image paths, in which case you could just look for column having the ".jpg", etc. extension as opposed to matching the whole path.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE col REGEXP '\.(jpe?g|gif|png)'
```

If you have the `col` with values like `/tmp/foo.gif` then it wouldn't match the `\w+` (word characters expression.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works perfectly. In case Thoman wants a sample, here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6dd9/3). Please ignore me using Zelda links :)